# Difference in behaviour when using a map comparator

Tags: c++, std

When declaring a std::map with a custom class is there any difference if I use a comparator as opposed to just implementing the less than operator for the class? Is one 'wrong' or considered bad?

Any difference between this:

```
std::map <MyClass, float, CompareMyClass> myMap2;
```

And this:

```
std::map <MyClass, float> myMap; // where MyClass has the less than operator implemented
```

Full Code:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:

        bool operator()(const MyClass& a, const MyClass& b) const
        {
            return a.value_ < b.value_;
        }

        bool operator<(const MyClass& myClass) const
        {
            return value_ < myClass.value_;
        }

    private:
        friend struct CompareMyClass;
        float value_;

};

struct CompareMyClass
{
    bool operator()(const MyClass& a, const MyClass& b) const
    {
        return a.value_ < b.value_;
    }
};

int main(int argv, char** args)
{
    std::map <MyClass, float> myMap;
    MyClass a;
    myMap[a] = 1.99;

    std::map <MyClass, float, CompareMyClass> myMap2;
    MyClass b;
    myMap[b] = 1.99;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the `operator()` overload in `MyClass` is not relevant, or?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I was thinking the same thing but I get compile errors without it. Could be the compiler version GNU C++11?

Comment: I don't believe you. What are those errors?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt nevermind, its happy if I remove it - not sure what happened there.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide an `operator<`, its behaviour should not be surprising. Now, for different uses, you might want to sort a record by different criteria, and for such a record, any `operator<` would always have surprising behaviour. In such a case, it is better to create a comparator who's name already gives a hint how it sorts, because it makes it explicit how a map (or other things) are sorted.